# Python: Convert Bytes inside a dict to json

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm having the following dict:

```
{b'one': b'one', b'two': b'two', b'three': b'three'}
```

I want to convert this to a `json` object.

I already tried different things with `json.dumps,` but I only get errors.

How can I do this?

Comment: What errors do you get and what code are you using to do the JSON dumps? Can you please [edit] your question to include that?

Comment: What sort of content do you expect the bytes to have? Are they going to be valid strings (UTF-8, etc), or arbitrary binary data?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you’re facing is due to the fact that the keys and values in your dictionary are bytes, not strings. The json.dumps() function in Python expects the keys and values to be of type str, int, float, bool, or None.

Use the following code to convert byte keys and values to strings;

```
dict_str = {k.decode('utf-8'): v.decode('utf-8') for k, v in dict_bytes.items()}
```